# How to create Circles of different sizes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am a newbie to `Designing`. I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/repeating-patterns-intro/), but I want to modify the output, I don't want so many circles. I want less number of circles placed randomly and also the sizes should be different. How can I do this in `Photoshop`?

Comment: Can you please tell us a bit more about the tutorial, or maybe post a picture? We'd like the question to be still relevent in the case the link breaks at a later time. Thanks!

Comment: I did not get any tutorial I just tried with brush. I will post the procedure as an answer to this question @Bakabaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open new file
make different circles in different shapes using ellipse tool
make this as a pattern image
edit-define pattern and save

open a new file
select pattern stamp tool and go to the top menu select newly created pattern
click and drag in the canvas,draw the pattern were ever u want......

also refer...
http://video.about.com/graphicssoft/Adobe-Photoshop-Pattern-Maker.htm

Comment: it worked. I think we can also do it with our own brush. I just now learnt.